# Flickr API check return type photo or video

Tags: json, flickr

When I query flickr api for media return data looks something like this:

```
"photo": [
{
 "id": "8432423659",
 "owner": "37107167@N07",
 "secret": "dd1b834ec5",
 "server": "8187",
 "farm": 9,
 "title": "Color",
 "ispublic": 1,
 "isfriend": 0,
 "isfamily": 0,
 "is_primary": 1,
 "has_comment": 0
```

I want to know which is photo and which is a video. I know there is a "media" parameter (photos|videos|all), however this will filter them in response. I want to return all media, but be able to distinguish between photos and videos, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [`flickr.photos.search`](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html), try adding the `extras` parameter and include `media`. You should then get a `media` property for each item returned, which indicates if it's a photo or video.